# Why is Tensorflow 2 custom Bijector / flow yielding the wrong number of samples?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

I am building a Tensorflow 2 Probability *Normalizing Flow* that contains a "custom Bijector".  The definition of that Bijector is:

```
class F3Bijector( tfb.Bijector ):
    """ 
    Represents bijector from [ z1, z2 ] to [ z1, z2 + a * z1 ** 2 ]
    """
    def __init__( self, a, **kwargs ):
        tfb.Bijector.__init__( self, forward_min_event_ndims = 0, **kwargs )
        self.a = a

    def _forward( self, z ):
        z1, z2 = z[ 0 ], z[ 1 ]
        return tf.convert_to_tensor( [ z1, z2 + self.a * z1 ** 2 ] )
```

When I use this in a TransformedDistribution thus:

```
dist = tfd.Normal( loc = [ 0, 0 ], scale = [ 1, 1 ] )
nf = tfd.TransformedDistribution( dist, F3Bijector( 8 ) )
print( "dist.sample(3)", dist.sample( 3 ) )
print( "nf.sample(3)", nf.sample( 3 )  )
```

I see the following weird results:

```
dist.sample(3) tf.Tensor(
[[ 0.637353    1.535212  ]
 [ 2.8678417  -0.3769277 ]
 [ 0.18412828 -0.03613231]], shape=(3, 2), dtype=float32)
nf.sample(3) tf.Tensor(
[[ 0.12927543 -0.20221345]
 [-0.18784967  0.0698643 ]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32)
```

What's weird is that the first "sample(3)" correctly returns 3 bivariate samples, but the second "sample(3)" applied to the TransformedDistribution yields only two samples.  Where's my missing sample?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem:  I was ignoring the batch dimension in my `_forward` method.  When I handled it, thus:

```
def _forward( self, z ):
    return tf.map_fn( lambda z2: tf.convert_to_tensor( [ z2[0], z2[1] + self.a * z2[0] ** 2 ] ), z )
```

it worked, and when I sampled the Normalizing Flow 1000 times, I got one thousand (transformed) samples.